# What figure of speech is this? "Homes to the homeless, jobs to the jobless"

Tags: figures-of-speech

What figure of speech is this?

Homes to the homeless,
jobs to the jobless

Comment: [**parallelism**, also known as **parallel structure** or **parallel construction,** is a balance within one or more sentences of similar phrases or clauses that have the same grammatical structure.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar)) (Wikipedia)

Comment: I think Wikipedia's first example is a much better one: *"The inherent vice of capitalism is the unequal sharing of blessings. The inherent virtue of Socialism is the equal sharing of miseries." — Winston Churchill*

Comment: Maxims to the maximless!

Answer (score 1):

The online Oxford Dictionary offers as the meaning of *figure of speech*:-

> a word or phrase used in a non-literal sense for rhetorical or vivid effect.

Your examples are not really examples of figures of speech on that definition.  So I tried the Oxford Companion to the English Language.  This tells us that the phrase is a translation of Latin *figura orationis*, which is in turn the Latin version of the Greek *σχημα της λεξεως (schēma tēs lexeōs)*.  It defines the term more broadly as:-

> a rhetorical device that achieves a special effect by using words in distinctive ways, such as *alliteration*, in which the same sound, especially an initial consonant is repeated ... and *hyperbole*, as in the phrase *tons of money* ('a great deal of money').

And on it goes, citing thirty two more!  One that is not cited is FumbleFingers' *parallelism*, but it is certainly appropriate to the OP's example.  It includes a lot of repetition, not of words so much as of **structure**.  So it has two parts of identical metric value (tum-ti-ti tum-tum), which happen to constitute the final two feet of the hexameter.  It also involves repetition of the words *home* and *job*.  More to the point, it uses contrast ) between *home* and its (sort of) opposite *homeless*.  These are all *parallel* elements, so I am only really confirming what FumbleFingers has suggested. Perhaps also, we could there is a kind of *anaphora*, which is only the Greek work for *repetition*, which is only the Latin for ... repetition.

So it is a very good slogan, because it is simple, direct and memorable.